# Show PHP echo after first login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cookies, authentication

I've build a small and simple login function on my website. There is no part/page to register so I've to sign up new users. I want to show some PHP echo with a password change field (an easy form connected to the SQL Database) which appears after the first (only once) login. Is there an easy way to set it up?

Comment: You need to give some more information on which system you are using. Additionally some code you have come up with so far would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3):

What about to create a field "**first_login**" in your DB with default 0 in the user table?
When they log in, you have to check it.

If first_login == 0 -> Show "change password form", else nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, an easy approach is to have a **login_attemps** (or whatever) table in your mysql database to store user's successful login attempts. This way you can see if a user is first logged in or not.

The table could have so many other tracking usages too!

Answer (score 0):

Create a field in your DB with `default 0` in your user table When user login, you have to check it.

```
If login == 0 -> Show "change password".
```

> And than update user table field to 1